# How to change the ids referenced in one dataframe to the ids that will be kept after the duplicates are removed from the second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with two dataframes:

`df` - contains multiple rows with data about scientific articles, including a `magazine_id` which is connected to the `ids` in the second dataframe

`magazines` - contains only 2 columns: `id` and `title`

In the `magazines` dataframe there are duplicate titles.

I am unsure about how to change the ids referenced in the first dataframe to the ids that will be kept after the duplicates are removed.

```
df = pd.Dataframe({'id': [1003, 1009, 1010, 1034], 
               'title': ['Article1', 'Article2', 'Article3', 'Article4'],
              'magazine_id': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
magazines = pd.Dataframe({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
               'title': ['Mag1','Mag1','Mag3','Mag4']})
```

So from `magazines`, entry with id = 2 should be deleted because it has the same title as id = 1.
The output for df should be:

```
id          title      magazine_id
1003    'Article1'      1
1009    'Article2'      1
1010    'Article3'      3
1034    'Article4'      4
```

Comment: Please provide samples of your two dataframes, and a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: @keramat you changed "rows" to "columns", but are you sure that was the OP's intention? I actually thought that was a mistake too, but if it's not...all the answers will be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have created two data frames that align with your problem statement
- de-dupe titles, keeping **list** of IDs that were used
- then *map* (**merge**) to re-align **title_id** of second data frame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": range(10), "title": np.random.choice(list("ABCDEFG"), 10)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"content_id": range(100), "title_id": np.random.choice(range(10), 100)}
)

# drop duplicates, keep original ids as list
df = (
    df.groupby("title").agg(ids=("id", list)).reset_index().assign(id=lambda d: d.index)
)

# map title ids in second data frame to newly de-duped ids
df2 = (
    df.loc[:, ["id", "ids"]]
    .explode("ids")
    .merge(df2, left_on="ids", right_on="title_id")
    .drop(columns=["id", "title_id"])
    .rename(columns={"ids": "title_id"})
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is not clear I made a scenario. If it is your case my suggestion is that first `merge` the dfs then use `drop_duplicates`. See the following:

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame({'title_id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'authors': ['w', 'e', 'w','e','w']})
titles = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5], 'title': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b','a']})
main_df.merge(titles, left_on='title_id', right_on='id').drop_duplicates(['title', 'authors'])
```

main_df:

[image]

titles df with duplicates:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `drop_duplicates` to get rid of duplicate titles, and use `ffill`:

```
magazines = magazines.drop_duplicates(subset=['title'])
df.loc[~df['magazine_id'].isin(magazines['id']), 'magazine_id'] = np.nan
df['magazine_id'] = df['magazine_id'].ffill().astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     id     title  magazine_id
0  1003  Article1            1
1  1009  Article2            1
2  1010  Article3            3
3  1034  Article4            4

>>> magazines
   id title
0   1  Mag1
2   3  Mag3
3   4  Mag4
```